# Intercept back event in an react app to confirm save

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, expo

I am building a react native app using expo.io.

The app is using a Stack Navigator to move between pages (cards).

My problem is that I have one page where users can create new items and I want to save the items when they leave the page.
Instead of saving all their changes, I want to prompt the user if they want to save changes before leaving the page so they get a chance to discard any changes they have made.

I have not been able to find an event for exiting the page that I can hook into and prompt the user if they want to save their changes?
The closest I have found to what I want to do is in [backhandler](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/backhandler), but that only works for Android back button.

Is there a way to do something similar if the user goes back with the back button in the header of the card, or if they use a swipe gesture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [NavigationEvents](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html). Add event listeners to your components.

> onWillFocus - event listener
>
> onDidFocus - event listener
>
> onWillBlur - event listener
>
> onDidBlur - event listener

for example, the following will get fired when the next screen is focused.In the other screen, save user's changes in temporary storage, when they navigate back, get those unsaved changes and prompt the user, whether they want to save or not.

```
focusSubscription = null;

onWillFocus = (payload) => {

  if (payload && payload.action && payload.action.type && payload.action.type === 'Navigation/BACK') {

    // get values from storage here
    // if there were unsaved changes prompt the user if they want to those changes or not
  }
};

componentDidMount = () => {

  this.focusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
    'willFocus',
    this.onWillFocus,
  );
 }

componentWillUnmount = () => {
  this.focusSubscription && this.focusSubscription.remove();
  this.focusSubscription = null;
};
```

[Demo](https://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/back-prompt-user)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add, I had looked at the mount and blur events for always saving when you left the screen, but I wasn't sure that I would be able to pop up a modal and suspend the transition while I waited for confirmation that the user wanted to save.

Thanks, I will have a look at what is possible with that tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

React Navigation added in version 5.7 the [beforeRemove](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/preventing-going-back) event which you can use for this.

This is the demo from their site:

```
function EditText({ navigation }) {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState('');
  const hasUnsavedChanges = Boolean(text);

  React.useEffect(
    () =>
      navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', (e) => {
        if (!hasUnsavedChanges) {
          // If we don't have unsaved changes, then we don't need to do anything
          return;
        }

        // Prevent default behavior of leaving the screen
        e.preventDefault();

        // Prompt the user before leaving the screen
        Alert.alert(
          'Discard changes?',
          'You have unsaved changes. Are you sure to discard them and leave the screen?',
          [
            { text: "Don't leave", style: 'cancel', onPress: () => {} },
            {
              text: 'Discard',
              style: 'destructive',
              // If the user confirmed, then we dispatch the action we blocked earlier
              // This will continue the action that had triggered the removal of the screen
              onPress: () => navigation.dispatch(e.data.action),
            },
          ]
        );
      }),
    [navigation, hasUnsavedChanges]
  );

  return (
    <TextInput
      value={text}
      placeholder="Type something…"
      onChangeText={setText}
    />
  );
}
```